# cgi-bin is duplicated when form action is called

Tags: apache, cgi-bin

I have a website on ipage and works fine. I am trying to migrate it to Google Cloud and the cgi-bin is duplicated when called by a form action as shown below:

```
http://34.28.183.10/cgi-bin/cgi-bin/list_directory_1.cgi?directory=%2CBrasil%2CMinas+Gerais&submit_trailing_directory=
```

It works if I remove the extra cgi-bin such as:

```
http://34.28.183.10/cgi-bin/list_directory_1.cgi?directory=%2CBrasil%2CMinas+Gerais&submit_trailing_directory=
```

I placed the script *list_directory_1.cgi* in */usr/lib/cgi-bin* and the form whose action calls this script looks like this:

```
print qq(<form action="cgi-bin/list_directory_1.cgi" method="GET">\n);
```

The apache2 log files shows this:

> [Thu Mar 16 14:39:49.939253 2023] [cgid:error] [pid 5389:tid 140165141997312] [client 107.217.8.189:52312] AH01264: script not found or unable to stat: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/cgi-bin, referer: http://34.28.183.10/cgi-bin/list_directory_1.cgi?directory=%2CBrasil&submit_directory=

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A URL that starts with a **relative path** (like `cgi-bin/list_directory_1.cgi`) is resolved by:

1. Taking the base URL (`http://34.28.183.10/cgi-bin/list_directory_1.cgi?directory=%2CBrasil&submit_directory=`)
2. Removing everything after the last `/` in the path (`http://34.28.183.10/cgi-bin/`)
3. Appending the relative path (`http://34.28.183.10/cgi-bin/cgi-bin/list_directory_1.cgi`)

Use an **absolute path** (starting with a single `/`) instead:

```
<form action="/cgi-bin/list_directory_1.cgi"
```

These are resolved by:

1. Taking the base URL (`http://34.28.183.10/cgi-bin/list_directory_1.cgi?directory=%2CBrasil&submit_directory=`)
2. Removing everything after and including the whole path (`http://34.28.183.10`)
3. Appending the absolute path (`http://34.28.183.10/cgi-bin/list_directory_1.cgi`)

Comment: @MarcosCamargo – The relationship between the URL path and the filesystem path is not relevant to this problem.

Comment: I have the same form specified in the index.html and it works the first time it is called but it doesn't work after that.

Comment: @MarcosCamargo — I am not surprised. This answer explains why and also how to fix it.